# Explain Lyapunov Stability

Tags: convex-optimization, lyapunov-functions

In my lecture notes, we have $$\dfrac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=f(\vec{x}),$$where $f$ is polynomial and $\vec{x}=0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an equilibrium.

In determining whether all trajectories $\vec{x}(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$, we want to find a Lyapunov function $V(\vec{x}(t))$ because $$\dfrac{d}{dt}V(\vec{x}(t))=\langle f(\vec{x}(t)),\ \nabla V(\vec{x}(t))\rangle.$$ I understand the derivation of that last formula, but I don't see how it helps determine whether all $\vec{x}(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: What does it meant for $f(\vec x)$ to be a polynomial when $\vec x$ is a vector?  Do you mean that the *components* of $f(\vec x)$ are polynomials?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I think it means $f$ is polynomial in the components of $\vec{x}$. So there will be monomials such as $x_1x_2^2x_5$.

Comment: @RobertLewis Actually what I just said would output a scalar, whereas $\dfrac{d\vec{x}}{dt}$ is a vector, so it's probably that each component of $f(\vec{x})$ is polynomial in the corresponding component of $\vec{x}$.

Comment: Page 10 (1-9 is background) at this Stanford link provides a proof of my question, but I'm still working to understand it: https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/lyap.pdf

Comment: Thanks I'm checking it out!

Comment: This is because of Lyapunov theorem. $f$ doesn't need to be polynomial, only sufficiently well-behaved to $\dot{x} = f(x)$ have an unique solution.

Comment: @Dan which step of the proof you are needing help?

Comment: @shamisen thanks for the clarification on $f$. I think I get the proof now. I posted the proof link right after I found it, but now it has digested